# Endomorphism of a type $III_1$ factor

Tags: von-neumann-algebras

Is a unital, injective, ultraweakly continuous $*$-endomorphism $f:M\rightarrow M$ of a $III_1$ factor $M$ inner? I.e. is there a unitary $U\in M:$ $f(-)=U(-)U^*$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Take any automorphism in the Tomita-Takesaki modular flow of M.
It is well known that an automorphism in the modular flow is inner if and only if M is semifinite.